# How can I remove a large empty space from my page?

Tags: html, css

I was working in my page and I have seen that there is a large empty space at right, I can see it moving the scrollbar. How can I remove it?

This is my code:

```
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Agenda - Central de Estudos</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos">
<meta name="description" content="Central de estudos. Todas as matérias. Temas abordados em sala de aula.">
<meta name="keywords" content="estudo, matéria, escola">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="G:/TRABALHOS/Central de estudos - Arquivos/header_style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="G:/TRABALHOS/Central de estudos - Arquivos/footer_style.css">
<style>
h1{text-align: center;}
h2{font-size: 18px;}
article{
    margin: 30px;
    height: 721.5px;
}
@font-face{
    font-family: Sepet;
    src: url(G:/Programação/Webdesign/Curso-de-Webdesign/Projeto-Fashion/Fontes/Sepet.ttf);
}
article img{
    width: 700px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 250px;
    left: 900px;
}
.handwriting{
    font-family: Sepet;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
    bottom: 150px;
}
.handwriting a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Central de Estudos<span>     <a href="file:///G:/TRABALHOS/Central de Estudos - Arquivos/index-login-on.html">Início</a> <a href="#">Matérias</a> <a href="file:///G:/TRABALHOS/Central%20de%20estudos%20-%20Arquivos/Exerc%C3%ADcios.html">Exercícios</a> <a href="file:///G:/TRABALHOS/Central%20de%20estudos%20-%20Arquivos/Agenda.html">Agenda</a> <a href="file:///G:/TRABALHOS/Central%20de%20estudos%20-%20Arquivos/Login-login-on.html">Login</a></span></h1>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/20/12/26/earth-3550553_960_720.png" alt="Globo escolar">
    </header>
    <main>
        <article>
            <h1>Agenda</h1>
            <hr>
            <h2>Tarefas</h2>
            <ul>
               <li>25/03/2019 | Ciências | Livro - Pg. 17 Ex. 7</li>
               <li>26/03/2019 | Português | Livro - Pg. 46</li>
               <li>26/03/2019 | Geografia | Caderno - Atividade 07</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Provas</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>26/03/2019 | Artes | Conteúdos abordados (diversos)</li>
                <li>01/04/2019 | Ciências | O ser humano (visão geral) e a célula (visão geral)</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Entrega de trabalhos</h2>
            <p>Não há trabalhos para entrega no momento.</p>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/14/41/opened-37229_960_720.png">
            <p class="handwriting"><a href="#">Aulas</a></p>
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>Autoria do site de Bruno M. B. Sdoukos.</p>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>`
```

I think there isn't a problem with margins, I already tried to put "margin: 0" in the "style" but it doesn't solve the problem.

Obs: The page is in a my computer's file, so I can not put here its URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to debug this yourself is to add the following `CSS` rule:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Doing so will show you immediately which elements are responsible for the scroll.

[image]

There are 2 elements causing the horizontal scroll due to their large `left` property values. Either remove these large values or rethink your layout to fit within the starting viewport.

```css
article img {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 900px; /* <-- Causing horizontal scroll */
}
.handwriting {
  font-family: Sepet;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1000px; /* <-- Causing horizontal scroll */
  bottom: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I removed the 'left:1000px' and it solved the problem. But can I position the text otherwise?

Comment: Did you also remove the `left: 900px` from `article img`?

Comment: Yes, now I need another way to position the text and the image.

Comment: @BrunoSdoukos Agreed. But that's a totally different question. I would start [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/flexbox-css-flexible-box-layout/) learning about Flexbox. Then, try your layout again and come back to SO if you get stuck.

Comment: @BrunoSdoukos If you’re happy with my answer, I’d be grateful if you could select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.handwriting{
font-family: Sepet;
font-size: 30px;
position: relative;
left: 1000px;
bottom: 150px;
}
```

That "left:1000px" is pushing

```
<p class="handwriting"><a href="#">Aulas</a></p>
```

way to the right causing white space for the rest of the page